# Why does the shell say there isn't an attribute keys?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried running this code and the shape didn't show up and the shell said that pygame didn't have and attribute 'keys'.[enter image description here][1]

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Game1")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 225), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Kindly post the whole traceback

Comment: Its a typo: `pygame.key.get_pressed()` rather than  `pygame.keys.get_pressed()`

Answer (score 1):

It says that because the line `keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()` should be `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`.